# rpm install in CentOS6 does not recognize dynamic library libc.so.6

Tags: libc, centos6, dynamic-library

I'm new to rpm and cannot find a way to get it to recognize .so files in /usr/lib, it cannot find libc.so.6 which is there. Is this related to the rpm build process or something I can perhaps modify. The man page did not have anything which appeared related to dynamic or libraries, which I believe the .so file to be.

```
rpm -ivh libusbx-1.0.16-1.fc20.i686.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17) is needed by libusbx-1.0.16-1.fc20.i686
libudev.so.1 is needed by libusbx-1.0.16-1.fc20.i686
libudev.so.1(LIBUDEV_183) is needed by libusbx-1.0.16-1.fc20.i686
```

Looking at the commands in the window below, does this mean that there is no libc.so.6 and if so what might have created the links?

```
$ ll /usr/lib/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 13 17:26 /usr/lib/libc.so.6 -> /lib/libc.so.6
$ ll /lib/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jul 12 20:01 /lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.so
```

Most importantly is there a safe way to update libc.so.6 on Centos 6.3 that will not somehow brick the box, as this dynamic library looks important. I did just update to glibc_2.17 which was part of a Fedora build, but I had this issue below so I'm thinking it's unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.so

This means that you have glibc-2.12

> libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17) is needed by libusbx-1.0.16-1.fc20.i686

The `libusbx` package requires glibc-2.17. Your distribution is too old.

> is there a safe way to update libc.so.6 on Centos 6.3

I could be wrong, but usually RedHat EL distributions (and CentOS based on them) do *not* allow you to upgrade glibc via standard update mechanisms.

And you are rightfully concerned about an update causing "bricked" system; whatever you do, proceed with extreme caution.